# passport wont execute after call

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Why wont my passport be executed?

Current output:

```
routing post login
using passport
```

and nothing more. `logging in` isnt even executed.

code from server.js ( only that has to do with passport).

```
var Account = require('PATH/app/models/Users.js');

var passport = require("passport");

var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
app.use(passport.initialize());
// persistent login sessions
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());



router.post('/login', function(req,res) {

    console.log("routing post login");
    console.log(req.body);

    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = 0;
    console.log("using passport");
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        function(username, password, done) {
            console.log("logging in");
            if (username == "admin") {
                var user = {username: "admin"};

                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false);
                }
              /*  if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) {
                    console.log("failing user verify");

                    return done(null, false);
                }*/
              console.log("authenticate local");
                passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
                    res.redirect('/');
                    console.log("redirecting");

                    console.log("returning done");
                    res.json({type: 'success'});
                    return done(null, user);

                });



            }
        }

    ));
});
```

Comment: You should probably take a look [at the `passport-local` example project](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example).

Comment: i tried that @robertklep but having the same problem.

Comment: But your Passport code setup is incorrect: `passport.use()` shouldn't be used inside a route handler, the use of `passport.authenticate()` is "creative", and the callback to it does strange things. That's why I suggested you'd start with a functioning example setup, and expand from there.

Comment: I'm only going to repeat that you should take a look at the example project. For example, this is how logins are generally implemented:
 https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/125e166444f0658ce08cc5e1db2c57f9a9bd92ac/server.js#L75-L79